# Cómo verificar que mi GetCell trae datos?

Tags: c#, excel

Estoy realizando un programa para tratar unos datos que vienen desde excel...
cuando un campo vienen vacio me manda error, ya le coloque varias restricciones pero sigue en lo mismo, que condición puedo usar para validar que este campo trae datos

```csharp
 List<VMACIS> lista = new List<VMACIS>();
                string fechaReport, reportDe, personaReporto, personaCometio, descripcion, area, tipoRiesgo, fechaHoraCierre;
                for (int i = 1; i <= cantidadFilas; i++)
                {
                    IRow fila = HojaExcel.GetRow(i);
                    if (fila.GetCell(0).ToString() != "" && fila.GetCell(1).ToString() != "" && fila.GetCell(2).ToString() != "")
                    {                        
                        if (fila.GetCell(0).ToString() != "") { fechaReport = fila.GetCell(0).ToString(); } else { fechaReport = " "; }
                        if (fila.GetCell(1).ToString() != "") { reportDe = fila.GetCell(1).ToString(); } else { reportDe = " "; }
                        if (fila.GetCell(2).ToString() != "") { personaReporto = fila.GetCell(2).ToString(); } else { personaReporto = " "; }
                        if (fila.GetCell(3).ToString() != "") { personaCometio = fila.GetCell(3).ToString(); } else { personaCometio = " ";  }
                        if (fila.GetCell(4).ToString() != "") { descripcion = fila.GetCell(4).ToString(); } else { descripcion = " "; }
                        if (fila.GetCell(5).ToString() != "") { area = fila.GetCell(5).ToString(); } else { area = " "; }
                        if (fila.GetCell(6).ToString() != "") { tipoRiesgo = fila.GetCell(6).ToString(); } else { tipoRiesgo = " "; }
                        if (fila.GetCell(7).ToString() != null || fila.GetCell(7).ToString() != "") { fechaHoraCierre = fila.GetCell(7).ToString(); } else { fechaHoraCierre = " "; }
                        lista.Add(new VMACIS
                            {
                                fechaReport = fechaReport,
                                reportDe = reportDe,
                                personaReporto = personaReporto,
                                personaCometio = personaCometio,
                                descripcion = descripcion,
                                area = area,
                                tipoRiesgo = tipoRiesgo,
                                fechaHoraCierre = fechaHoraCierre,
                            });
                    
                    }
                    else i= cantidadFilas;
                }

                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, lista);
            }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que fila? que error tira?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las validaciones son incorrectas, por ejemplo lo estas realizando de esta forma:

```
if (fila.GetCell(0).ToString() != "") { 
   fechaReport = fila.GetCell(0).ToString(); 
} else { 
   fechaReport = " "; 
}
```

pero debes usar `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(..)` de esta forma,

ejemplo:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fila.GetCell(0).ToString())) { 
   fechaReport = fila.GetCell(0).ToString(); 
} else { 
   fechaReport = " "; 
}
```